# Compatible version of Shapely Library with Python 3.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, shapely

I am using AWS GLUE of version Glue 4.0 , Python 3.0 and trying to external Library of Shapely.
I tried some version -
shapely-2.0.2-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Shapely-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Shapely-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win32.whl
shapely-2.0.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
shapely-2.0.2-cp312-cp312-win32.whl

but nothing worked.
Can any one have idea which version I should with python 3.0
also should I use linux or win .

Answer (score 0):

Glue 4.0 runs on python 3.10 not 3.0.

Also, Glue runs on Linux not Windows.

I did some tests for you and it seems `shapely==2.0.3` would work for you. To add it to your glue job, add `--additional-python-modules`, `shapely==2.0.3` in your **Job Parameters**.